# i want to add values to jtextpane in java

Tags: java, string, addition, jtextpane

I have :

```
String value=(jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString());

jTextPane1.setText("\n"+value);
```

I want to add value to jTextPane without overwriting last value , for exemple I want in jTextPane :    ( selected item 1 
                 selected item 2
                      ....
                                 )

this code give me the last selected item  , please help

Comment: If your issue has been solved, then please choose an accepted answer below (checkmark).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the previous text, you simply need to append your next text to the previous text. Like so:

```
jTextPanel1.setText(jTextPanel1.getText() + "\n" + value);
```

The `setText()` method removes any previous text, and sets it with the given value, while `getText()` returns the current text. So appending your new value to the value of `getText()` would return

```
old value
new value
```

Comment: This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content.

Answer (score 0):

```
String value=(jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString());

jTextPane1.setText(jTextPane1 + "\n" + value);
```

You're overriding the value if you leave it like:

```
jTextPane1.setText("\n"+value);
```

Because comboBox's text let's say is: "A", "B", "C".

Then your jTextPane1 text's: "A", then it changes value for "B" and then for "C", instead you read it's value and "A B C".

You can make an idea of what I'm saying by using a debuger